# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{n^\sqrt n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{n^\sqrt n}$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$

I've tried several approaches but failed (I guess my limit evaluation ability is a bit rusty).

I'd be glad for guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a> 0$:

Compute the $\log$:
$$
\log a_n = n \log a - \sqrt n\log n 
$$

Now two cases:

- $a\le 1$: $\log a_n\to-\infty$ and  $a_n\to 0$
- $a>1$: you can prove that $$\log a_n > \frac 12 n\log a $$ for $n$ big enough. Hence
  $a_n\to \infty$.

If $a=0$: 
this is $0$.

If $a<0$:
Use the results for $a>0$ with $|a_n| $ instead of $a_n$.

Comment: What if $\;a<0\;$ ?

Comment: Can you explain the first equation please?

Comment: @AlonAlon:$$\log\frac{a^n}{n^{\sqrt n}}=\log a^n-\log n^{\sqrt n}=n\log a-\sqrt n\log n$$using basic properties of logarithms:$$\log x^m=m\log x\;,\;\;\log\frac AB=\log A-\log B$$ All the time, of course, the logarithm's argument's assumed to be positive.

Comment: Thank you @mookid and @Timbuc!

Comment: @Timbuc i edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

$\log a_n = n \log a - \sqrt n\log n=n \cdot(\log(a)-\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}})$ and $\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ is well known to have a limit of $0$.

Comment: You're assuming $\;a>0\;$ since you use $\;\log a\;$. What if $\;a\le 0\;$ ?

Comment: Can you explain the first equation please?

Answer (score 1):

== If $\;a=0\;$ the limit is zero

== If $\;-1<a<0\;$ then both $$\;\begin{cases}a^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\\{}\\\frac1{n^{\sqrt n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\end{cases}\;\implies\frac{a^n}{n^{\sqrt n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$$

== If $\;a<-1\;$ then $\;\{a^n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ swings between positive and negative values, so our only chance for convergence is if the denominator of the sequence converges to zero faster than the numerator, so taking even $\;n$' s to make things positive, we have a case already covered by other answers.